# Dynamically resolving jquery collection values

Tags: jquery

This is probably just a case of getting the right approach to do the job.

I have a jQuery collection and I am looping through it for each item, 
Then I need to dynamically append a "Tab" and create a `click` event handler.

However, I need to resolve a value from the collection and use it in the event, as a hardcoded value. At runtime, the collection object does not exist and my code returns `undefined`.

```
var i = 0;

// Load them with 
$(result).each(function () {
  // Appending the Tab Here                     
  $('#nav-tab').append('<a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab' + i.toString() + '" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">' + this.TAB_CONTENT + '</a>');

  // Some code to execute if we click on the tab
  $('#nav-contact-tab' + i.toString()).click(function() {
    // This is where my problem is: 
    // I need to make the assignment below as a value.
    daTabID = this.TABLE_NAME;
    alert(this.TABLE_NAME);
    LoadReport();
    alert('Report Loaded done');
  });

  i++;

  alert(i);
});
```

Comment: first you don't need to call `i.toString()` since `i` will automatically be converted to string when doing `"somestring" + i`

Comment: second you don't need to have a counter. the `each` method will count for you

Comment: third `this` in the `each` callback will contain the element of the current loop, so `this.TABLE_NAME` is undefined

Comment: Appreciated - The counter is just there to create unique ids for the appended tabs.

Comment: ok, but you just can `$(result).each(function(e, i) { ... });`

Comment: @Sampgun if you do it properly you don't need that at all

Comment: I don't do anything, because I don't use jQuery anymore ahaha I moved to Angular. If HE does properly...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I just wanted to guide him to the solution, rather than give a taylor-made solution he won't learn anything from..

Comment: If that's a jab at my question it has a full description of the best pattern to use to solve this problem. I'd argue that's more useful to someone learning than giving them some half-baked line of code which leads to a less than ideal solution, which also fails to address the underlying issue of scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly note that incremental `id` attributes are an anti-pattern and should be avoided. Secondly note that `this` in `$.each()` will refer to the element in the iteration, not the outer scope which holds the `TABLE_NAME` and `TAB_CONTENT` properties.

The simplest and DRY-est way to achieve what you require is to use common `class` attributes along with `data` attributes to hold custom metadata about the element(s). Then you can use a single delegated event handler instead of creating a new one in each loop. Try this:

```js
var $tab = $('#nav-tab').on('click', '.nav-contact-tab', function() {
  var daTabID = $(this).data('table-name');
  console.log(daTabID);
  LoadReport();
});

$(result).each(function() {
  $('#nav-tab').append('<a class="nav-item nav-link nav-contact-tab" data-table-name="' + this.TABLE_NAME + '" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">' + this.TAB_CONTENT + '</a>');
});
```